# What are the current gold standards for volatility prediction error?

Tags: volatility, garch, forecasting

I'm working on volatility forecasting models for equities and currencies. I am using daily data and am interested in producing forecasts for the next `n` days. To evaluate model error I am looking at two metrics, `mean absolute percentage error` and `directional accuracy`. What are the state of the art benchmarks for these two metrics?

Comment: I don't know. But here is a public source of volatility forecasts vlab.stern.nyu.edu/doc?topic=vlab . See if you can do better.

Comment: I've seen people using the ratio as error metric, as in Jim's slides, http://tpq.io/p/rough_volatility_with_python.html